# PaloAlto theme in beamer : logo

Tags: beamer

In PaloAlto theme, I would like to have the logo on the top right corner instead of the top left corner so that the sidebar begins at the top left.

Any Idea ?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Redefine the headline template to place the logo flush right and to suppress the draker square on the upper left corner:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \hfill\hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
          \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\logo{\includegraphics[height=\beamer@headheight]{ctanlion}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame One}
CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it would probably be nicer to have the logo in white instead of black with a transparent background: maybe illegal?

Comment: @pluton yes, a white image with transparent background would be appropriate for this design.